# How to keep the animation property within that element which is at top

Tags: html, css, animation

I have made a class popup which  contains simple animation bounce..The html part goes like:-

So how to prevent the animation in popup from going to id open-btn
The CSS goes like this:-

```css
.slanted {
  margin-left: 440px;
  /* transform: skewX(25deg); */
  color: yellowgreen;
  font-size: 54px;
  /* margin-top: 16px; */
  overflow: visible;
  animation-name: bounce;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@keyframes bounce {
  from {
    margin-top: 0px;
  }
  to {
    margin-top: 16px;
  }
}

#open-btn {
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  font-weight: bolder;
  font-size: 32px;
  background-color: rgb(47, 47, 236);
  width: 270px;
  height: 80px;
  margin-top: 350px;
  margin-left: 520px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="popup">
  <div class="slanted">
    I am Veer Shah
  </div>
</div>
<div id="open-btn">Download CV</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you are using **margin** property for the animation. When you increase the top margin of a div element it causes all the html elements below it to shift downward by that amount thus making it seem like the open-btn element is also a part of the animation. For your animation to work properly use the proper position property in CSS. [Here](https://www.freecodecamp.org/learn/responsive-web-design/applied-visual-design/create-movement-using-css-animation) this might help.